# How to get remaining jio data with java

Tags: java, android

How can i make a java or android code to automatically check my jio data balance for every 2 hours. If remaining data is more than 50%, how to execute certain url/file?

tried [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/) but don't know what exactly it was and how it works.

I need the reaming balance(data) of the user.

Comment: search if Jio provides an API for developers to check account info, if they provide you can use that fetch a response such as JSON and parse it and find your answer

Comment: You can use any proxy software to proxy traffic through your PC via WLAN. You may have to install SSL certificates into your Android device to intercept SSL connections. From there see how they do the work.

This guy has done somewhat like this on JioMusic : https://github.com/vikas5914/JioMusic-API